# Julia using view of an array to return a vector

Tags: julia

This has some relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507845/julia-vector-of-matrix-or-3d-array):

I am trying to get a slice/subarray of an N-dimensional array.
The slices are, by construction, vectors of known length, but for the sake of generality let's supposed they are some arrays of lower rank `M<N`, whose dimensions are known a-priori.
I want to operate on these slices (as arguments) for functions that takes `Array` of rank `M` or a `Vec`, rather than an `Array` with a bunch of singelton dimensions (so `Vec` and not `Array{N}` with dimensions `(n,1,1,1,1...)`).

For example I would like to have `view(A,indx...)` return a reference (SubArray?) with rank 1 and size `(n,)` and not rank `M` with `(n,1,1,1,...)`.
I understand that `view` naturally keeps the type of `A` to be type-stable, but I really do not want to make the functions work on arguments of size `(n,1,1,1,...)`...
And of course, defining an array of the correct size and going through the `setindex!` path is almost certain slower.

Any suggestions / ideas / wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` already returns a `SubArray` with the right size, without extraneous dimensions:

```
julia> M
3×3×3 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

[:, :, 2] =
 10  13  16
 11  14  17
 12  15  18

[:, :, 3] =
 19  22  25
 20  23  26
 21  24  27

julia> a = @view M[2:3, 2:3, 2]
2×2 view(::Array{Int64, 3}, 2:3, 2:3, 2) with eltype Int64:
 14  17
 15  18

julia> size(a)
(2, 2)

julia> a = @view M[2:3, 2, 2]
2-element view(::Array{Int64, 3}, 2:3, 2, 2) with eltype Int64:
 14
 15

julia> size(a)
(2,)
```

However, note that a `SubArray` is not an `Array` i.e. if you wrote a function to accept only `Array{Int, 2}` arguments, it won't accept `SubArray{Int, 2 ...}` as passed-in values.

Instead of being overly specific with argument types in this way, it's better to accept any `AbstractArray`, write your code in a generic way (eg. using `eachindex`, etc.), and explicitly check the dimensions or size with `ndims` or `size` within the function body if necessary.

Comment: Maybe I have failed to explain myself properly: if I use `A=rand(3,3,2)` I get a `3×3×2 Array{Float64, 3}`. Taking `B=view(A,:,1,1)` will indeed produce `size(B) (3,)`, however it will be a `SubArray`  of `::Array{Float64, 3}` . While this is not a problem per-se, I need a mechanism that ensures that this will be dispatched to a function that operates on "1D" vectors and not an N-dimensional array.

Comment: What do you mean by "a function that operates on "1D" vectors"? How are you defining this function?

Comment: I'm using `func(othervar::<irrelevant to our dicussion>, var::Base.AbstractVecOrTuple{<:Number}) = <operation>` for when it only has 1 dimension of non-singelton indices. And it is important since if it were a 2 or more non-singelton indices, the operation in the function needs to be different (and therefore the dispatch)

Comment: That should work fine. `B` is a `SubArray{Float64, 1}` which is a subtype of `AbstractVector`, so that dispatch should work fine for this. The size of the parent array doesn't matter for the purpose of this dispatch.

Comment: the reason it didn't work is eventhough the view produced a "1-dimensional" `size=(n,)` entity, the type was still defined as `::SubArray{Float64, 3,...)` which is not a subtype of Base.AbstractVecOrTuple (while `::SubArray{Float64, 1,...)`  is)

Comment: How did you get a `SubArray{Float64, 3,...)`? More code and context in the question would definitely help.

Comment: I would love to help, but I already made changes and not sure how to reproduce this (did not git commit the version that did not work as it... did not work). I tried, but got `::SubArray{Float64, 1,...)` as expected...  Sorry about that.